# setTimeout function not working with for loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, slideshow, settimeout

I'm trying to run this code to make a slideshow of 3 images, but it's not working properly. The slideshow runs once, but then just stops...

Below is my JavaScript, CSS and HTML, and if you run the code snippet you will see the slide show run once.

The HTML is basically declaring a container div with the slides as divs wth a specific background image. (For this question I changed the images to colors so you can see the slideshow in action)

The CSS declares the position of each of the images of the slideshow when it is in plain view and when it is hidden.

The JavaScript cycles through the slides giving each one a class of "hidden" when they are supposed to move out of view. At the end, it brings back the first slide by removing all the "hidden" classes.

I'm pretty sure the issue is in the JavaScript with the setTimeout function since whenever I run the functions in the console it works perfectly, but when I try to automatically set them to run in my JS it only runs once.

```js
function slide1to2(){
 document.getElementById('slide1').className = "hidden";
 clearTimeout(s1to2);
}
function slide2to3(){
 document.getElementById('slide2').className = "hidden";
 clearTimeout(s2to3);
}
function slide3to1(){
 document.getElementById('slide1').className = "";
 document.getElementById('slide2').className = "";
 clearTimeout(s3to1);
}

for(i=0; i<100; i++){
 s1to2 = window.setTimeout(slide1to2, 2000);
 s2to3 = window.setTimeout(slide2to3, 4000);
 s3to1 = window.setTimeout(slide3to1, 6000);
}
```

```css
div#slideshow{
 width:100%;
 height:50%;
 background-image:url("white-wall.png");
}

div#slideshow div{
 width:100%;
 height:inherit;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:center;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 position:absolute;
 transition:1s;
}

div#slideshow div[id$="1"]{
 background:#FF8888;
 transform:translateX(0%);
 z-index:3;
}

div#slideshow div[id$="2"]{
 background:#88FF88;
 transform:translateX(0%);
 z-index:2;
}

div#slideshow div[id$="3"]{
 background:#8888FF;
 transform:translateX(0%);
 z-index:1;
}

div#slideshow div[id$="1"].hidden{
 transform:translateX(-100%);
}

div#slideshow div[id$="2"].hidden{
 transform:translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
 <div id="slide1"></div>
 <div id="slide2"></div>
 <div id="slide3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `setTimeout()` is asynchronous.  It doesn't block execution until the timer fires.  Instead, it just schedules a timer for some future time and continues execution of your javascript.  So you're scheduling 300 timers in your `for` loop, all at three separate times.

Comment: Put some console.log statements inside your slideAtoB functions and you'll see that you get 100 logs statements all at the same instant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working with this: 
(Thanks Yotam Salmon for your answer, thats what helped me understand what I was doing wrong)

I basically got each function to set the timeout and run the following one, then i got the last one to run the first one again. all i needed then was to start the first one manually then it just ran forever.

```js
function slide1to2(){
    document.getElementById('slide1').className = "hidden";
    setTimeout(slide2to3, 4000);
}
function slide2to3(){
    document.getElementById('slide2').className = "hidden";
    setTimeout(slide3to1, 4000);
}
function slide3to1(){
    document.getElementById('slide1').className = "";
    document.getElementById('slide2').className = "";
    setTimeout(slide1to2, 4000);
}

slide1to2();
```

```css
div#slideshow{
 width:100%;
 height:50%;
 background-image:url("white-wall.png");
}

div#slideshow div{
 width:100%;
 height:inherit;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:center;
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 position:absolute;
 transition:1s;
}

div#slideshow div[id$="1"]{
 background:#FF8888;
 transform:translateX(0%);
 z-index:3;
}

div#slideshow div[id$="2"]{
 background:#88FF88;
 transform:translateX(0%);
 z-index:2;
}

div#slideshow div[id$="3"]{
 background:#8888FF;
 transform:translateX(0%);
 z-index:1;
}

div#slideshow div[id$="1"].hidden{
 transform:translateX(-100%);
}

div#slideshow div[id$="2"].hidden{
 transform:translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
    <div id="slide1"></div>
    <div id="slide2"></div>
    <div id="slide3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you realize that this is almost exactly what I posted?  Yet, you didn't mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 4):

When you `setTimeout()`, the code doesn't wait for the timeout to finish. That means that your `for` loop is executed 100 times after 2 seconds, another 100 times after 4 seconds, and another 100 times after 6 seconds.

Instead of that, you can re-set the timeouts after the third frame is finished.

An example of simple loop with timeouts:

```
var i = 0;
function a() {
   //Do some stuff
   if (i++ < 100) setTimeout(a, 1000);
}
```

This ^ is good. A bad example would be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        //Do stuff
    }, 1000);
}
```

The first will execute 100 times with interval of 1 second, the latter will execute 1 time.

Answer (score 1):

You could get same effect without using JS with CSS3 animations (not exactly the same code, you should play with the times and the styles a little bit)

https://plnkr.co/edit/2AtRK7z9OJhs4AwX82rx?p=preview

```
.animation--slideshowAnimation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  animation-duration: 12s;
  animation-name: slideshowAnimation;
  animation-delay: 0;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: forward;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, your loop effectively does nothing, as `setTimeout` is asynchronous.

One way to achieve the result you want is to set the callback function in each one.  Then set another function which will clear the timeouts.  To loop forever, just remove the `stopTransitions` function and its caller.

https://jsfiddle.net/24aLyg5v/

```
var timeout1, timeout2;

function slide1to2(){
    document.getElementById('slide1').className = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('slide2').className = "";
    timeout1 = window.setTimeout(slide2to1, 2500);
}

function slide2to1(){
    document.getElementById('slide2').className = "hidden";
    document.getElementById('slide1').className = "";
    timeout2 = window.setTimeout(slide1to2, 2500);
}

function stopTransitions() {
    clearTimeout(timeout1);
    clearTimeout(timeout2);
}

window.setTimeout(stopTransitions, 20000);
slide1to2();
```